# extjs adding icons to the titlebar of an extended window widget (two levels of extension)

Tags: extjs

I am new to extjs....
I am trying to add icons to the title bar of a window.
I am not able to figure out the error in my code
i tried using tools config for the window

Here is my code:

```
**Ext.ns('DEV');
DEV.ChartWindow = Ext.extend(Ext.ux.DEV.SampleDesktopWidget, {
width:740,
height:480,
iconCls: 'icon-grid',
shim:false,
animCollapse:false,
constrainHeader:true,
layout: 'fit',
initComponent : function() {

this.items = [
    new Ext.Panel({
        border:true,
        html : '<iframe src="" width="100%" height="100%" ></iframe>'
    })
];

DEV.ChartWindow.superclass.initComponent.apply(this, arguments);
},
getConfig : function() {
var x = DEV.ChartWindow.superclass.getConfig.apply(this, arguments);
x.xtype = 'DEV Sample Window';

return x;
},
tools: [{
id:'help',
type:'help',
handler: function(){},
qtip:'Help tool'
}]
});
Ext.reg('DEV Sample Window', DEV.ChartWindow);**
```

SampleDesktopWidget is an extension of Window

Can somebody help me with this

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

I believe ***title*** is part of the header. I dont think you can do this with initialConfig programmatically but you can either override part of component lifecycle or hook in with an event. E.g. add this to config. You might (probably) be able to hook in at any early stage after init maybe, but thats an experiment for you.

```
listeners: {
  render: {
    fn: function() {
      this.header.insert(0,{
        xtype: 'panel',
        html: '<img src="/img/titleIcon1.gif"/>'
        });
      }
   }
}
```

However for this particular scenario I would use iconCls

```
iconCls: 'myCssStyle'
```

Then include a CSS file with:

```
.myCssStyle {
   padding-left: 25px;
   background: url('/ima/titleIcon.gif') no-repeat;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a good example that might help, using `extjs 3.2.1`.

[Adding tools dynamically](http://www.rahulsingla.com/sites/default/files/content/blog/extjs/extjs-panel-add-tool.htm)